# default constraints for property type

Tags: grails, constraints

In `Config.groovy` one can specify default constraints that will apply to all properties, e.g.

```
grails.gorm.default.constraints = {
    '*'(nullable: true)
}
```

Is there a way to specify default constraints for properties of a certain type? For example, if I want to add a `(blank: false)` constraint for all `String` properties is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about adding a default constraint for a certain type, but in [Programming Grails](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920024750.do), Burt suggests a filter to handle blank fields:

```
class SiteFilters {
    def filters = {
        blankToNullAndTrim(controller: '*', action: '*') {
            before = {
                if (request.post) {
                    convertBlanksToNullsAndTrim(params)
                }
                true
            }
        }
    }
    private static void convertBlanksToNullsAndTrim(Map map) {
        def keys = [] + map.keySet() // copy to avoid
        //ConcurrentModificationException
        for (name in keys) {
            def value = map[name]
            if (value instanceof String) {
                value = value.trim()
                if (value.length() == 0) {
                    map[name] = null // don't remove - explicity set to null
                } else {
                    map[name] = value // update if trimmed
                }
            } else if (value instanceof Map) {
                // recurse with empty nested param, e.g., "location":["id":""]
                convertBlanksToNullsAndTrim value
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With that there's no need to add `blank:false`.

Also, in Grails 2.3.x this behavior changed: by default all blank and empty Strings will be converted to null during data binding (configurable).

Comment: So a Grails 2.3 app has no need for this filter or the `blank: false` constraint, right?